# calculate mean and min of lists with None types included

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, mean, min

I have to calculate the mean of the following list:

```
j=[20, 30, 40, None, 50]
```

And also the min values from these nested lists which also includes the same:

```
x = [[20, 30, 40, None, 50], [12, 31, 43, None, 51]]
```

Which should return `[12,30,40,50]` but the following code is not working.

```
print(list(map(min, zip(*x))))
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

And for the mean I tried this:

```
import statistics
statistics.harmonic_mean(j)
```

None of them worked on this type of list.

Answer (score 3):

You can filter out the "None" values to get the mean and mins. For example:

```
from statistics import mean

data = [[20, 30, 40, None, 50], [12, 31, 43, None, 51]]

mean_val = mean(d for d in data[0] if d is not None)
print(mean_val)
# 35

min_vals = [min(a, b) for a, b in zip(*data) if a is not None and b is not None]
print(min_vals)
# [12, 30, 40, 50]
```

Comment: The condition is wrong `if d` is false also for zeros, but they are perfectly valid numbers. Correct is `mean_val = mean(d for d in data[0] if d is not None)`